# Make SourceMap of Website only visible for some reasons

Tags: javascript, production, source-maps

Currently I added sourcemap to production version of website in order to track errors/bugs from other tools (such as [SEntry](https://sentry.io/welcome/)).

But I dont want everyone could get my website's structure on the internet. So how could I config sourcemap only visible for SEntry or some request URL?

Answer (score 0):

Don't upload them to your web server.

Sentry supports [uploading a source map to them directly](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/javascript/sourcemaps/#hosting-source-map-files).  For Chrome Developer Tools, just right-click your minified file and click "Add Source Map".